# Oracle Sql Statement to ignore string literals

Tags: sql, oracle, select, plsql

I have a simple query which has an `IN` clause, i.e.

```
select *
  from customer 
 where dept_name in ('red', 'blue')
```

Now I am trying to put dept_name into a string variable like this:

```
dept_name_list := 'red';

select *
  from customer
 where dept_name in (dept_name_list);
```

--this works.

But the issue is how can I make Oracle ignore " ' " when I have to build the string like this:

```
dept_name_list := ''red', 'blue'';

select *
  from customer
 where dept_name in (dept_name_list);
```

here, dept_name_list returns error?

Any suggestions??

Update: I tried to escape single quote by doing something like this:
`dept_name_list := '''red'', ''blue''';`

It compiles but no result is displayed.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a type that represents a table of varchars and use that within your select.

Here is a [link](http://www.williamrobertson.net/documents/comma-separated.html) that explains and shows you how to use types in this way.

Answer (score 3):

```
DECLARE
  TYPE tbl_str IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2 (30) index by binary_integer;
  l_array tbl_str;

BEGIN
   l_array(0) := 'Red';
   l_array(1) := 'Green';
   l_array(2) := 'Blue';

  select *
  from customer
  where dept_name in TABLE(CAST(l_array AS tbl_str ));
END;
```

Should do it

Comment: @sanjeev40084 Cannot try from here... can you please try the updated code?

Answer (score 1):

You can escape quotes like this:

```
dept_name_list := ' ''red'', ''blue'' ';
```

But that won't help you unless you are dynamically building your SQL like this:

```
v_sql := 'select * '
 ||        'from customer '
 ||       'where dept_name in (' || dept_name_list || ')';
```

Then you can open your cursor like this:

```
OPEN out_cur FOR v_sql;
```

Comment: how do you execute the sql then

Comment: That depends what you're doing. Are you trying to loop through the resulting rows? Are you opening a reference cursor? Are you trying to return a specific column into a variable?

Comment: this is what happens:
OPEN out_cur FOR
select **
from customer
where dept_name IN ..

Comment: ok got this error this time: ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-01003: no statement parsed

Comment: It sounds like one of your SQL strings is empty. i.e. either `OPEN out_cur FOR '';` or `OPEN out_cur FOR 'SELECT * FROM customer WHERE dept_name IN ()';` Make sure the string contains valid SQL before you try to use it.